# How to account for multiple raters in an exploratory factor analysis?

Tags: mixed-model, random-effects-model, factor-analysis, structural-equation-modeling

I have a dataset on which I want to perform an exploratory factor analysis. There are ~150 subjects that are rated by ~25 raters on ~70 items (the items are about certain behaviors of the subjects). Different subjects can be rated by different people, and different people can rate different subjects as well (~500 observations in total).

I suspect that perhaps the raters could be accounted for by including them as random effects? Is that possible in an exploratory factor analysis context? Or would another approach be more suited?

Comment: I don't know any way of handling that. I would aggregate to the item level, you might want to do this in a mixed model framework, e.g. by including rater as a random effect.

Comment: Check out `PLmixed` in R. It might be possible to use that for these purposes. https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/PLmixed/vignettes/PLmixed_intro.html

Comment: (IIUC) that will let you do a CFA / IRT model, but not an EFA.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fit the EFA to the rater corrected data, that is 
1) in two steps: correct for rater using a random effects model, save the rater corrected data, and do the EFA
2) in one step (Mplus?) fit the EFA and include a random rater factor.

Before you do this obtain a indicator of the rater effects, e.g., intraclass correlation.
you have 70 items. but that is no a problem calculate the 70 iccs, plot them. If you find that rater effects are negligible, you can ignore them and just do the EFA.

Btw: 1) EFA with 70 items and 150 cases can be a bit of a challenge (many items, low N). So in the EFA, I'd keep things parsimonious (few common factors) and focus on interpretability.
2) If the item response format is dichotomous, then you might want to consider calculating the tetrachoric correlations and submitting the tetrach cor matrix to the EFA 
(simple in R using function factanal and library polycor).

Comment: Let say I have ratings on 25 different dimensions that I want to factor analyze, and each of these are rated by n subjects. When I run the random effects model, would I do it on all ratings at once, or separately for each dimension?